# Android SyncAdapter

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am writing a syncadapter using google account and app engine. The account appears in account and sync, but when I try to select the account for syncing, I am getting a hard database error. I am trying to figure if this error is on mobile or the app engine. Further, what can be causing this error

Another error that I am getting is failed to find provider info.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm going to do an appengine account with the syncadapter also.  Curious, did you ask for username and password?  I am using the user API on appengine for accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had not added the provider in manifest. It should be something like this:

<

```
provider android:name=".BlaBlaProvider"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.blabla"
            android:syncable="true" />
```